# How to create BashOperators within PythonOperator in Apache Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I am creating some BashOperators within PythonOperator but it is not working. 
Task t1 reads conf parameter from the context have and return a value and second task t2 which is Python operator read the value using xcom, I am able to read the value but task in for loop are not create.

Is it Possible to create a BashOperator in PythonOperator?

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime


def load_properties(comment_char='#', sep='=', **kwargs):
    #some processing
    return kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get('propname')


def createtask(**kwargs):
    property_from_task1=ti.xcom_pull(key=None, task_ids='t1')
    for value in range(property_from_task1):
        task = BashOperator(task_id=task_name, bash_command='echo creating a commond', dag=dag)



default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 12, 21),
    'provide_context': True,
}




dag = DAG(
    'param', default_args=default_args,schedule_interval=None)

t1 = PythonOperator(task_id='t1',
                    python_callable=load_properties,
                    provide_context=True,
                    dag=dag)


t2 = PythonOperator(task_id='t2',
                    python_callable=createtask,
                    provide_context=True,
                    dag=dag)


t2.set_upstream(t1)
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are calling PythonOperator operator to build BashOperator, which airflow won't realize that until it execute the code. I am not aware of a way you can do that with compile time.

You can try to take your for loop out and build your bash operator from there, you might need to have

```
property_from_task1 = load_properties()

for value in range(property_from_task1):
        task = BashOperator(task_id=task_name, bash_command='echo creating a commond', dag=dag)
```

I find having a config file (YAML, JSON) then parse it as `property_from_task1` might be easier but it depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow DAGs are already written in Python, so no need to generate operators within an operator. Further to Chengzhi's answer, here is a working snippet I use to chain commands sequentially:

```
operators = [BashOperator(task_id=step,
                          bash_command=command,
                          dag=exec_ssh) for step, command in commands.items()]

for upstream, downstream in zip(operators[:-1], operators[1:]):
    upstream >> downstream
```

In this example, "commands" is a dictionary of your steps that you can load from a JSON or some kind of config. You can extend it to build out DAGs with parallelism, branching, etc. Self-generating DAGs are the best!